# Is it possible deploy and run war-application with javaagent on Wildfly/JBoss?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, javaagents

How to deploy and run war-application with javaagent on Wildfly/JBoss? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add agentlib as startup option to Wildfly/JBoss, so yes, sure it's possible. However, if you just want to run the application with agentlib without Wildfly/JBoss classes being iterated, that you wouldn't be able to do, as java agents work on JVM level. So all classes in runtime JVM would be iterated, including Wildfly/JBoss classes.

Comment: So the JavaAgent would be applied to the whole jboss server and not an individual application? is it possible to have different agents for each application?